# Where is Spark copying jars on worker nodes?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've some 3rd party jars in my Spark code, bundled using maven and submit.

1. Want to know, whenever we submit our spark job, where it copies all the required 3rd party jars in the worker node?
2. Can we configure that path so that spark could copies jars there only in worker nodes? if yes, then where it can be configured?
3. There is a change in 3rd party jar which I used to use in my Spark code and didn't change the jar version. So while running with a new jar with the same version name`(1.1.1)`, it's still picking old jar(`1.1.1)`. Any suggestion, what can be done?

Comment: you can pass jars during spark-submit command using --jars option

Comment: @Vish, that's not my question, want to know where its gets copied, can it configured ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the spark official documentation on https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management, it seems like the jars supplied by --jars option are copied to the local working directory of the executor which means it gets copied to a local temp path on your disk where your resource manager such as yarn has access to. I will strongly recommend against modifying this path as it would create a bunch of complexities. Again looking at the above link there is a property `spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl` which can be used to trigger an automatic cleanup if you are not using a resource manager like yarn/mesos (which already have a cleaup mechanism of there own).

Looking into your question, it seems like you are doing an uber/fat jar for your spark application where your 3rd party jar seems to be a dependency managed by maven and gets copied to the uber/fat jar. Given the 3rd party hasn't done a update on the version of their jar, your maven seems to be picking up the old jar. For that you cab purge your local maven repo (which resides in `$home.dir/.m2` dir on your local system. Please do not delete files manually from here instead use the `purge` option/command in maven to do that. The command is `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`

For documentation on purge, please refer to http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html